# openwrt: dns resolving error from wifi connected devices

Tags: dns, openwrt

I am not sure what have I messed up, but I cannot resolve other pc's in my local network from the wifi-connected devices (laptops and cell phones).
I have a separate tower-pc that acts as a dns and dhcp server (among other things) so from openwrt, I thought I was forwarding the dns the requests to that dns server. apparently something is wrong and I cannot pin-point it.

observations:
1. from all wifi-clients, I can get a FQDN be resolved. So if my intranet domain is "xsolutions.office." and I `nslookup pc1.xsolutions.office` , this will work file. What does not work is `nslookup pc1`.
1. if I ssh into the openwrt router and `nslookup pc1`, it works as well:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# nslookup  pc1
Server:    192.168.112.112
Address 1: 192.168.112.112 srv.xsolutions.office

Name:      pc1
Address 1: 192.168.112.161 pc1.xsolutions.office
```

2. nslookup from a windows laptop , does not work at all. not even with FQDN!

these are my dns and wireless info:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uci show | grep wireless
wireless.wl0=wifi-device
wireless.wl0.type=broadcom
wireless.wl0.channel=auto
wireless.wl0.txpower=18
wireless.wl0.hwmode=11gst
wireless.wl0.txantenna=3
wireless.wl0.rxantenna=3
wireless.@wifi-iface[0]=wifi-iface
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].device=wl0
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].network=lan
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].mode=ap
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].ssid=OpenWrt
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].encryption=psk2
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key=*********
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].doth=1

root@OpenWrt:~# uci show | grep dns
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0]=dnsmasq
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].localise_queries=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].rebind_protection=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].rebind_localhost=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].expandhosts=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].readethers=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].leasefile=/tmp/dhcp.leases
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].resolvfile=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].server=srv.xsolutions.office
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].logqueries=1
dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].domain=xsolutions.office.
network.lan.dns=192.168.112.112
ucitrack.@dhcp[0].init=dnsmasq
```

could you help out?

thank you!